# Is this a viable method of relative benchmarking image load time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, benchmarking

The basic thing is, I, being obsessed with keeping track of everything I can easily...want to keep track of image load times.  I don't expect/desire perfection (e.g. It is 100% accurate, down to the millisecond, for every image load). The goal is relative accuracy (e.g. If between 10am-11am, the average is 100ms load time. It suddenly starts spiking to an average of 3s a few hours later, I'd like to know that sort of thing).

Thoughts if this solution is sufficient for that? Or did I miss something obvious?

Yes, I know it doesn't report anything anywhere...that isn't the purpose of the example code, it is merely to calculate the time.

Example Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Timing Test Page</title>
</head>
<body style='background-color: black; color: white;'>
This is a page.

<div class='test' id='t1'>
    <img id="1" src='/test.jpg' />
</div>

<div class='test' id='t2'>
    <img id='2' src='/test2.jpg' />
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery.imagesloadded.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded -->
<script>

var Performance = window.performance.timing;

function ImageLoadTime(ImageTime, id)
{
    if(Performance.loadEventEnd > 0)
    {       
        console.log("Image Load Time ["+id+"] " + (ImageTime-Performance.navigationStart) + " milliseconds");
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){ImageLoadTime(ImageTime, id)},250);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').each(function(index) 
    {
        var temp = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).imagesLoaded( function( $images ) 
        {
            var d = new Date();
            ImageLoadTime(d.getTime(), temp);   
        });
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you're doing, but why not use the Google Chrome developer tools  for this? The network tab has a very nice display of all things coming over the wire, how much time they took for request and transfer, etc...

Here's a screenshot of it on this page:

[image]

Comment: The entire purpose of it is to be able to see what results other people besides me are getting. It would also not let me see the change in results over time which is the entire value of it. Seeing real world results over a period of time greater than 'one page load'.